# How can I avoid that a functions argument touches the brackets using unicode-math?

Tags: spacing, luatex, miktex, unicode-math, luaotfload

Maybe, I am doing something wrong, but please have a look on the alignment in this formula:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[%
    ,math-style=ISO
    ]{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
$f(T)= T\cdot \dots$
\end{document}
```

[image]

That's not very beautiful. The "T" headnuts the right bracket and there is a lot of free space below the T (the brackets are too low). I could add some `\,` or similar, but I guess, I just don't know how to set a function.

---

**Edit:** The compilation with XeLaTeX works fine. But I need it with LuaLaTeX. 
The Lua-version is: "LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013062820 (rev 4627)" 
I am getting a lot of

```
luaotfload | load : auto-selecting default features for script: dflt
luaotfload | load : path lookup of "latinmodern-math.otf" unsuccessful, falling 
back to file:
```

in my `main.log`

Comment: At least on my system (TL2013, fairly recently updated) the output of your example has correct spacing (both with Lua- and XeTeX).

Comment: I've added my filelist. Maybe you could have a look if you can see the old package. My MiKTeX 2.9 is fresh installed and up to date. There is no good practise for setting functions like `f(x)`, isn't there?

Comment: regarding the "space below" within the parentheses, the height and depth of the parentheses are designed to accommodate letters like the "f", where you can see that the space above and below is symmetrical.  in math (for which these fonts were designed), you don't want different sized parentheses for simple expressions that are baseline-aligned; it simply looks ugly.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you, I just noticed that symmetry to the "f" when I uploaded my picture. Well then I think I just have some horizontal problems here.

Comment: More important than the file list you posted are probably the versions of LuaTeX (`beta-0.76.0-2013061708  (TeX Live 2013) (rev 4627)` on my system) and `latinmodern-math.otf` (1.958). Also, try compiling with `xelatex` and see if the output is better.

Comment: @Caramdir see my update. I think, luaotfload has some problems.

Comment: I don't know enough about the internals of luatex's font handling and MikTeX to help you with that. For further testing you could try using a different font (eg. XITS Math).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The file `luatex-unicode-letters.tex` differs between TL2013 and MiKTeX. The TL version deactivates (comments) all entries from `\l 1D400` to `\l 1D7CB`
and contains the comment:

```
 % XXX: luatex math italic correction bug
 % http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2011-October/030295.html
```

This sound as if there is a bug in LuaTeX and Tex Live has implemented a workaround by not setting some catcodes. If I copy the `luatex-unicode-letters.tex` to MiKTeX, update the FNDB and recreate the LuaLaTeX format the spacing is correct in MiKTeX too.

Comment: Thank you! Should I report this to MiKTeX or to the LuaLaTeX team?

Comment: I added a small bug report to the luatex tracker. You can inform miktex so that is uses the work-around too. The file luatex-unicode-letters.tex from TL is here http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/generic/config/.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2287/ It has been "fixed" in MiKTeX. The commented version will be available in the next update.