# Using unicode-math makes an equation ugly

Tags: unicode-math

Using `unicode-math` makes following equation ugly. Is it a bug? How to solve that?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$-| P |<r_u<|P|$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ugly = ? Are you talking about `P` touching the right vert? I don't get it with Miktex 2.9.

Comment: I don't get it with MiKTeX XeLaTeX, but I get it with LuaLaTeX. I think LuaTeX is not as stable and mature software as XeTeX.

Comment: Works fine with both `xelatex` and `lualatex` here (up to date TeX Live 2013). Could possibly be the same issue as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131717/how-can-i-avoid-that-a-functions-argument-touches-the-brackets-using-unicode-mat/

Comment: @HarishKumar Yes, I mean that. I am using  xelatex/texlive2012/win7

Comment: You could try upgrading to TeX Live 2013, perhaps a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to an outdated version of the software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading from texlive 2012 to 2013 solved the issue.

Thanks all for comments.